# plot coordinates from two vectors into a 0,1 matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have two vectors of equal length

```
a <- 1:10
b <- sample.int(10,size=10)
```

I would like to plot them into a matrix of the same length (10) where a is the row coordinate, b the column coordinate, with the value 1 for the coordinates and 0 for everything else. I have below a way to do this using a for loop, but was hoping to do this without a loop. Thanks!

```
matrix01 <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

for(i in 1:10) {
   matrix01[i, b[i]] = 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Use `replace` and `cbind` like this:

```
replace(matrix(0, 10, 10), cbind(a, b), 1)
```

**2)** In the question `a` equals 1:10 and in that special case (but not more generally) another possibility is:

```
+ outer(b, 1:10, `==`)
```

or

```
+ sapply(1:10, `==`, b)
```

**3)** In the question `a` is 1:10 and `b` is a premutation of 1:10.  In that special case (but not more generally) this works:

```
diag(10)[b, ]
```

**4)** In the question both `a` and `b` are premutations of 1:10 and in that special case (but not more generally) this works to give a `table`:

```
table(a, b)
```

This would also work and is similar:

```
xtabs(~ a + b)
```

### Note

Note that the question

- uses `seq(1:10)` which should be just `1:10`
- needs to add `set.seed` to make the input reproducible
- defines `a` but then does not use it in the code

Answer (score 1):

You can create a row/column matrix using `cbind` and assign the value 1 to those position.

```
matrix01[cbind(a, b)] <- 1
```